# How to pass an argument when configuring custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a custom `UITableViewCell`, lets call it `CustomCell`. All I need is to pass an argument when creating it, lets say a `NSURL`.

This is what I've done so far in my `ViewController`:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
[myTableView registerClass: [CustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier: @"CustomItem"]
```

In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
static NSString *myIdentifier = @"CustomItem"
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier]
```

All this works great, but I need to configure the cell with this one `NSURL`, but just once, not every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. I've noticed that `initWithStyle: reuseIdentifier:` in `CustomCell` is being call just once, but how can I add the `NSURL` with this call?

Comment: Do you want to add URL in all cells of TableView?

Comment: Yes, but different URL each time.

Comment: Did you saved the URL in any array?

Comment: I have access to the URLs in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and I need to set it once, but only once, not every time cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called. Is this possible?

Comment: *set it once* please clarify?

Comment: I don't want to [cell setURL: url] for each time cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called, just when it is being initialized.

Comment: ßo you want to add URL to only the first cell?

Comment: No, to all the cells. So, it is possible to pass arguments when initialising a custom cell?

Comment: So simply add the `url` in your custom cell `Label`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just load an `NSArray` inside `viewDidLoad`. Inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you add the URL from your `NSArray` and insert it into the `UITableViewCell`.

```
static NSString *myIdentifier = @"CustomItem"
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier]
[cell.labelURL setText:_arrayURLs[indexPath.row]];
```

Everything you have to do is to add a new property to your **CustomCell** called **labelURL** and connect it with a `UILabel` inside your `UIStoryboard` or `xib` file.

And think about, you can't just set them once. `UITableViewCell` will reuse its `UITableViewCells` and will always set another value multiple times to the same object. Thats why you have to do it this way and not only once.

Comment: Okey, this was more of an answer to my question: "you can't just set them once", fair enough. The purpose with the URL is to load a picture, and I want the CustomeCell to do a UIViewAnimation after the picture is loaded, how do i do that? I have all the code for the animation and loading etc., but now I load the picture each time cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called :P

Comment: you should do this in background with `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`. You could create a method inside your **CustomCell** and if a cell will be selected by clicking the sell already knows its `NSURL` from **labelURL**. If you don't have too many pictures you could also load them `asynchronous` while the `UITableViewController` will be loaded and save them to a dictionary so everything would work easier but looks like your not talking about just 10 `UIImages``

Comment: And because of the concept of reusing cells, it's impossible for cells to have their own variables, am I right? So what i really need is to let the datasource handle this?

Comment: Ok because of reusing it might be complicated this way. But you know the order of your `UITableViewCells` and so you could get the selected row inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and add a `UIImage` to the specific cell

Answer (score 1):

`UITableViewCell` of the same type should be reused using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. If you want a `property` to stay the same it should go in area **A**. If you want it to change every cell it should go in area **B**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";
    CustomCell *cell = 
      [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
       // (A) everything inside here happens once 
       // for example

       cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    // (B) everything here happens every reuse of the cell
    // for example

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",
                            (long)indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Because of the [feedTableView registerClass:[CutomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomItem"], the cell will never be nil, therefore the A area never will be called...

Comment: In that case if you're creating static cells, which it seems like you are, it sounds like you can put it inside that method?